# unable to use mysql.connector library because of syntax error?

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to use Python to manipulate a mySQL database. I successfully ran the code using Windows 7 earlier however I am unable to run the same code on Ubuntu.

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 running on VirtualBox and mySQL version is 14.14 Distrib 5.7.18.

My code is:

```
import mysql.connector
try:
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(database="cookbook",
                                 host="localhost",
                                 user="cbuser",
                                 password="cbpass")
    print("Connected") 
except:
    print("Cannot connect to server")
else:
    conn.close()
    print("Disconnected")
```

which worked well before.

And the error message is:

> Programming Error:(1064,"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1")

Comment: That error cannot possibly be coming from this code, especially as you catch all exceptions so the only thing it could do is print "cannot connect". Please show the actual code, and the *full* traceback.

Answer (score 0):

[Full Image of Error Arises from the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oel07.png)